# Is working with Cognos SDK the best option to show a report on a webpage?

Tags: java, web-services, cognos

I was asked to look into a way to integrate cognos reports into our web-app using java.
I have looked into a couple of online material,forums such as motio,cognoise etc and found out that there are few of ways to achieve it. (Please correct if I am wrong).

1. iframes and javascript
2. Cognos SDK
3. Cognos Mashup services

I feel that using Cognos SDK serves our requirement to support drill down, scheduling.

I just wanted to know if there is any other way through which we can achieve the functionality including the drill down and scheduling.

Also please provide the resource that contains the documentation and examples to work using Cognos SDK

Comment: Cognos also has portlets:  [Clicky!](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_10.2.2/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cra.10.2.2.doc/c_deployingcognosportletstothird-partyportals.html%23DeployingCognosPortletstoThird-partyPortals?lang=en)

Comment: Where can i find documentation to work using Cognos SDK